# Show free SSD space after TRIM / UNMAP / Deallocate?

Tags: ssd, nvme, trim

For a hard drive supporting ATA TRIM, SCSI UNMAP, or NVMe Deallocate, is it possible to report on the amount of unallocated space?

For example, we take a 1TB drive, then write 500GB data to it, then delete 300GB. Is there any command to show that the drive itself (not the filesystem) has 200GB used / 800GB free?

Answer (score 2):

On my nvme ssd, `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1` reports

```
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          2.048.408.248.320 [2,04 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            352.739.127.296 [352 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 b211b408d5
```

I couldn't find a way to see this for sata ssds.